Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) sends push notification to System tray when app is foregrounded
Context
As per the FCM documentation on Android Message Handling, push notifications will only be displayed if the App is backgrounded. It is not possible for a notification to appear in the System Tray while the App is foregrounded.

However! I have an app built with Capacitor. The app is currently on beta using the Internal Testing tool suite of the playstore. On it, when sending push notifications, I receive them through the onMessageReceived callback AND the System Tray even when the app is foregrounded.
According to the documentation, that shouldn't be possible. So, I thought maybe (without being able to confirm):

Did I read the FCM documentation wrong?
The Internal Testing is preventing FCM from correctly detecting if an app is foregrounded (although I don't think so, since onMessageReceived get triggered)
Something is wrong with Capacitor (I am using an old and unsupported version, so I wouldn't be surprised of unintended behaviour)
Something wrong about the FCM message format I'm sending (see below)?

An example of the FCM message package I'm sending using the firebase-admin SDK (latest version). This is a notification message with the optional data payload provided:
{
  data: { // data },
  notification: { title: "My title", body: 'My body' },
  android: { notification: { priority: 'max', visibility: 'public' } },
  apns: { payload: { aps: [Object] } },
  tokens: // token
}

Some observations:

On iOS (Capacitor being cross-platform), I get the same behaviour with a notification in the System Tray and the callback triggered
On Android, notifications that appear when the app is foregrounded are not clickable
When the app is backgrounded, I get notifications in the System Tray as expected. Those work as intended and are clickable (eg. they open the app and trigger the correct callbacks)
I just updated from a very old firebase-admin SDK (that was using the now-closed legacy APIs) to the latest version of the SDK. Before, I didn't have this kind of issues.

My question (finally)

Is this issue caused by the Internal Testing? If so, that would indicate to me that the live version will work as expected
If not, did you ever encounter this issue? If so, did you fix it and how?
If not, do you have an idea what could be the issue?

What I tried

I've tried removing the android.notification.priority and .visibility props, but I get the same issue.
All the research I've done point to topics and posts discussing if it was possible to send a notification to the System Tray while the app is foregrounded. While I am in that situation, but want to get out of it (truly ironic).


I realy have no idea, but the only thing that looks unusual to me is that you have both android specific notification payload as well as the firebase/outer notification payload.  In my flutter/firebase app, I only use data and notification — no android or ios necessary.  Maybe they are designed to be mutually exclusive?

I tried to remove the outer notification payload, but it didn't fix it. I will keep this question open, maybe it'll fix itself when I deploy to production. Thank you for the comment!

If you need to get onMessageReceived when the app is in foreground and background, You should send notification object as null and use data object for sending data as follows
{
  data: {  title: "My title", body: 'My body' },
  notification: null,
  android: { notification: { priority: 'max', visibility: 'public' } },
  apns: { payload: { aps: [Object] } },
  tokens: // token
}


That doesn't exactly answer my problem unfortunately. I already have the onMessageReceived calls. What I do NOT want are notifications in the system tray when the app is foregrounded (which I have), but still have them when the app is backgrounded.

If you send notification object, firebase will show the notification in the notification tray

Yes but according to the documentation (linked in the question), the notification should only go in the tray when the application is backgrounded. But I have notifications in the tray even if the app is foregrounded. Which isn't possible according to the docs, and yet I have it.
